# Why is builtin mail app search not finding results?

Tags: email

Recently I was searching for a particular phrase in an email a few days back, and the search results in builtin mail app didn't show it at all - just a bunch of completley unrelated old ad-mails.

Searching on computer web interface showed the recent emails I had read that actually were the correct ones.

Is there a bug fix or better Outlook mail app?

Comment: Had the expected results been downloaded to your phone? What sort of mail account was this for (Exchange/IMAP/POP3/etc?)

Comment: Normal Outlook Online webmail, and even when I say to search on server it didn't find the more recent one I wanted.